# Flutter: Trust anchor for certification path not found

Tags: flutter, ssl, flutter-inappwebview

I have got a website e.g. https://xyz.website.com. It's opening perfectly in the android mobile browser.
In my flutter application, I am using [inappwebview](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_inappwebview). When I am trying to load that particular web page in web view, it is giving the following error...

**I/cr_X509Util(17385): Failed to validate the certificate chain, error: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.
E/chromium(17385): [ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(981)] handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -202**

This problem is happening in android only. It's working fine in iOS.

Any idea, how to resolve this issue?

Comment: [try this may this answer help you](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6378872/14285339)